# IEEE 754 to decimal in C language

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, decimal, transform, ieee-754

I'm looking the best way to transform a float number to its decimal representation in C. I'll try to give you an example: the user introduces a number in IEEE754 (1 1111111 10101...) and the program has to return the decimal representation (ex. 25.6)
I've tried with masks, and bitwise operations, but I haven't got any logical result.

Comment: Why don't you use the standard-library-functions?

Comment: I can use <stdio.h> only

Comment: This is actually a non-trivial task, and thus too broad for a StackOverflow question. Relevant papers are: *Guy L. Steele, Jon L. White: "How to print floating-point numbers accurately". ACM SIGPLAN Notices, Volume 25 Issue 6, Jun. 1990, pp. 112-126.* as well as *Robert G. Burger, R. Kent Dybvig: "Printing Floating-Point Numbers Quickly and Accurately". In Proc. of the ACM SIGPLAN ’96 Conference on Programming Language Design and Implementation, 1996, pp. 108–116.*

Comment: Take a look what's in that header then: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io

Comment: Further relevant literature reference: *Florian Loitsch: "Printing floating-point numbers quickly and accurately with integers". ACM SIGPLAN Notices, Vol. 45, No. 6, June 2010, pp. 233-243*

Comment: @njuffa: To print the number out, you can use `printf` (which is in `stdio.h`). That's not the problem here; the problem is punning the binary representation.

Comment: @giorgioW `printf` is part of `stdio.h`, surely you can use that? i.e., `printf("%f\n", your_floating_point_number);`, or `sprintf` if you want it sent to a string... Am I missing something?

Comment: Thats it @rici, I can actually save the three parts of the number in three different variables, but I can't apply to them a mask because there is a conflict between types.

Comment: @Xophmeister The problem is to convert the binary representation of the number to its decimal.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question. As written, it seemed to suggest to me that the conversion is to be accomplished manually, as surely any C programmer would be aware of `printf()`. If the question is about type punning instead, use `memcpy()` which is legal in both C and C++, or use a `union`, which is legal in C99.

Comment: @giorgioW: Search for type punning. (Although you should find lots of warnings that it's a bad idea.) You could use ldexp, but it's in math.h

Comment: @njuffa I tried making bitwise operations to each part of the number, and then doing an OR of the results. in fact, this is the solution if you do it manually in a piece of paper, but C programmer doesn accept this.

Comment: @giorgioW At this point it is not clear to me what exactly your inputs consist of, what restrictions are placed on the processing, and how you are trying to accomplish that processing. I would suggest posting code that shows your current effort and then asking specific questions about that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following is performing the operation you describe:

I use the `int` as an intermediate representation because it has the same number of bits as the float (on my machine), and it allowed easy conversion from the binary string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

union {
    int i;
    float f;
} myunion;

int binstr2int(char *s)
{
    int rc;
    for (rc = 0; '\0' != *s; s++) {
        if ('1' == *s) {
            rc = (rc * 2) + 1;
        } else if ('0' == *s) {
            rc *= 2;
        } 
    }
    return rc;
}

int main(void) {

    // the input binary string (4 bytes)
    char * input = "11000000110110011001100110011010";
    float *output;


    // convert to int, sizeof(int) == sizeof(float) == 4
    int converted = binstr2int(input); 

    // strat 1: point memory of float at the int
    output = (float*)&converted; // cast to suppress warning
    printf("%f\n", *output); // -6.8

    // strat 2: use a union to share memory 
    myunion.i = converted; 
    printf("%f\n", myunion.f); // -6.8

    return 0;
}
```

As @DanielKamilKozar points out, the correct type for that `int` is `uint32_t`. However, that would require including `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: An `int` doesn't necessarily have the same number of bits as `float`. An `uint32_t` does.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar you're correct, I've added a note. Was just trying to stay within the requirement of only including `<stdio.h>`

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: If we go pedantic, let's go whole hog: There's no guarantee a `float` is IEE754 single-presicion floating-point. Though I guess we can argue that's a precondition of the question...

Comment: @Deduplicator: sorry, you're right. The float type is IEEE754 single precision as a precondition. I supposed it because I thought that is included in the C11 standard of C in that way

Comment: @Deduplicator: Further whole hog: which IEE754 single-precision floating-point: [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) or [decimal32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal32_floating-point_format)?

Comment: @thelaws: I tried your solution, but the compilator returns to me an error: "error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
     float *output = &converted;"

Comment: @giorgioW I put an explicit cast to suppress that error. Also added a second strategy that uses a union to share the memory.